# Why are wicket pages serialized?

Tags: wicket

When I ask for a page, I see it serialized and stored on disk (and in the 2nd level cache), after it is rendered, so in the detach phase. Also the page itself is stored in the session.

When I ask for the page again, it is found in the session. So the serialized page is not consulted.

When I ask for the page in another session, the page is created anew. I thought that in this case the serialized page would have been used.

So can you give me an example, a scenario, where the serialized page is read from disk (or 2nd level cache)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this url trace:

- direct your browser to your app:
  http://localhost:8080/
- Wicket creates an instance of the homepage and redirects to:
  http://localhost:8080/?0
- direct your browser to your app once again:
  http://localhost:8080/
- Wicket creates another instance of the homepage and redirects to
  http://localhost:8080/?1
- now press the back button so your browser requests the first instance again:
  http://localhost:8080/?0

The first page instance is now deserialized from disk.

Answer (score 2):

The http session keeps a **live** reference only to the page which has been used in the last request cycle. Any older pages are only in the disk. If your users use the browser back button then the old instance is loaded from the disk.

A file on the disk is used to store the pages per session. I.e.different users have different files with their own pages. Sharing the files would be a security issue, it is like sharing the http sessions.

Extra info: The disk storage is part of Wicket and used as default persistent storage. WicketStuff-DataStores module provides implementations with Redis, Hazelcast, Cassandra and Memcached. They could be used in case you want the old pages to be available in a cluster of web servers.

Comment: Thanks. I will try these data stores out.